# Bi-phenyl degradation pathway in lignin

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, enzymes, climate-change

I am studying lignin - and really like the bi-phenyl degradation pathway of DDVA by SYK-6, as shown below

[image: bi-phenyl degradation pathway]

But I can't find any literature on whether this pathway transfers from the dimer to the oligomeric lignin.

Do you think this pathway translates to oligomeric degradation of the 5-5' bond in lignin?